# Chrome is not sending the HTTP Headers while fetch image from AWS Bucket

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, fetch-api

Request header is not present on fetch request in Chrome.
(This same request is working on Mozilla)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cors.html

> The request's Origin header must match an AllowedOrigin element

[image]

Also i have already enabled `CORS` Policy on Bucket.

Please suggest me where i am doing mistake!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: yes @JaromandaX. But no request header present in request. Can you please help me out of this ?

Comment: @JaromandaX This same request is working on Firefox.

Comment: @JaromandaX I have already removed the MODE. Now AWS giving CORS error because ORIGIN is not present in header.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes i have installed Nimbuzz, AdBlocker and CyberGhost. Should i remove all these three adons ?

Comment: @JaromandaX i removed all these three adons and restarted chrome. Giving same result as before http://i.imgur.com/FtuZYX4.png

Comment: @JaromandaX I have checked Edge Browser and same result. https://ibb.co/gM9MHm9 .

Comment: @JaromandaX Please have look to my code. https://codeshare.io/loEr9R

I am using Angular v12 for this.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes i have checked our 3 Systems and Also checked on Client MAC OS. And its giving same error. 

Also when i use XHR. Same thing happening with me. IDK whats happening with me ? Do you need screen recording for more clarify ?

Comment: @JaromandaX Please check screen recording both browser -> https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ND-LcLsCdGjQGzAN_u_DX1rEN5F6HenD?usp=sharing

Comment: no, I know what "there's no request headers" means - I just don't get why only chrome is having the issue, and why chrome works fine for me (except I get a 403 error - but request headers are sent)

Comment: Damn it - there's no request headers when the request is fulfilled by chromes cache

Comment: @JaromandaX That's why i m confused. You can solve it bro. I believe (:

Comment: try adding a "cache buster" to the url ... `\`?_=${Math.random()}\`` - of course, in the developer tools you can just disable caching :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Bro you are Genius. `disable caching` is worked for me. Now i am trying ?_=${Math.random()}. Thanks a lot bro

Comment: @JaromandaX Bro you are such a Great Genious.`?_=${Math.random()}` Its worked for me. http://i.imgur.com/2HFRWpc.png . Please post you answer i will accept you answer immediately. Bro please let me know where learned these things.

Comment: Can't add an answer unfortunately